# Filtering Get-aduser on csv contents

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv formatted like

```
ln,fn
jones,bob
jagger,mick
```

and I am trying to get the mail attribute out of AD for these users by running the following:

```
$names = import-csv .\names4.csv
FOREACH ($name in $names){
get-aduser -f {surname -eq "$name.ln" -and givenname -eq "$name.fn} -pr mail
}
```

This returns nothing at all.  if I echo $name.ln it shows a list of users first names from the csv so I am unsure why the above command is not returning any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the context of an expandable string (ie. in double-quotes), the powershell parser only expands references up to the `.` - simply remove the `""` quotes:

```
$names = Import-Csv .\names4.csv
foreach($name in $names){
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Surname -eq $name.ln -and GivenName -eq $name.fn} -Properties mail
}
```

Alternatively, assign each property value to it's own variable:

```
$names = Import-Csv .\names4.csv
foreach($name in $names){
    $sn = $name.ln
    $gn = $name.fn
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Surname -eq $sn -and GivenName -eq $gn} -Properties mail
}
```

---

In any other situation where you need to dereference a property inside an expandable string, use the `$()` subexpression operator:

```
"The last name is $($name.ln)"
```

But I would advise against it with the ActiveDirectory module, as the `-Filter` block has some quirks with nested expressions

Comment: I guess he need to mention first name and last name in csv.

I would rather do this `Get-ADUser -Filter *  -Properties EmailAddress | select EmailAddress,SamAccountName 
 Export-CSV c:\results.csv -NoTypeInformation` and filter users i require

Comment: @Owl `-Filter *` will return every single user in the domain from the DC. That's ridiculously excessive if he's only interested in specific users.

Comment: When I ran w/o quotation i received the following error "get-aduser : Property: 'ln' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'."   But when i assgned each fn and ln their own var, it worked....thanks mathias!

Comment: A little more on this... When you expand a variable within a double quoted string it's referred to as [String Interpolation](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=string%20interpolation). As the name suggests, this is designed to work with strings, and what you have are objects, with properties. Those properties are strings, but the object you are referencing directly is not. Creating a sub-expression works because the sub-expression outputs the property value as a string, and not the `PSCustomObject` itself.

Comment: @200mg yeah, as mentioned at the end, `-Filter` can be a bit quirky, but if you "prepare" the arguments and assign them to individual variables it'll work